# Batch file tokens ignore empty delimiters

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to load a column from a CSV file into a variable. My CSV file contains empty columns so can have `,,` which seems to be ignored by the following:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=," %%a in (csvfile.csv) do (
    set date=%%a
    echo %%a
)
```

So if file `csvfile.csv` contains

```
fred,wilma,tony, john, greg, wilber, blake
chris,,steve,deon,bryan,mark,anthony
```

I would like the result:

```
tony
steve
```

But I get:

```
tony
deon
```

If I put a white space in the empty column this does work as expected.

How do I set `delims` so it does not ignore empty columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` treats consecutive delimiters as one. In most cases, this is helpful. Sometimes it is not.

So you have to write your lines in a way, that `for` can handle as you intended.

Read every line of your file as a whole, add a quote at the beginning and at the end and replace every `,` with `","`, resulting in

```
"chris","","steve","deon","bryan","mark","anthony"
```

This can happily be parsed with another `for`. The tilde in `%%~b` removes the surrounding quotes.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in (csvfile.csv) do (
  set line="%%a"
  for /f "tokens=3 delims=," %%b in ("!line:,="^,"!") do echo %%~b
)
```

Comment: Don't you need to put additional outer `""`, like `(""!line:^,^=","!"")`, as the outer ones are consumed by the `for /F` command?

Comment: @aschipfl astonishingly that worked (at least for token <> 1). Also astonishingly your suggestion doesn't work. See my edited code.

Comment: it worked for me, I just tested it successfully; note the changed escaping; anyway, it seems that `~` relies on the leading `"` but not on the trailing one; by the way, the `-` in `echo -%%~b` is a typo, right?

Comment: not exactly a typo. More a relict of `echo` debugging. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36372429.txt"
SET "oneline="

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 FOR /f "tokens=3delims=," %%h IN (" !line:,= , ! ") DO (
  SET "column=%%h"
  SET "oneline=!oneline! !column:~1,-1!"
  ECHO(!column:~1,-1!
 )
)
ECHO %oneline:~1%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `filename1` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36372429.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Unfortunately, you haven't shown us a realistic data sample. I'm very suspicious of your use of `date` as the destination variable.

`date` is a "magic variable" - maintained by the system as the current date. It can be overridden, but it's not advisable to do so.

It's not really clear what you want out of this procedure. Perhaps you want the entries from column 3 all on line line as you state, or perhaps you want to list only column 3 or perhaps you'd want the output transferred to a new file.