# i dont want to consider multiple ocurence of delimiters as one

Tags: batch-file

i am new to batch scripting. While trying to display only a specific token from a file , i am geting a mis aligned text
this is my code

```
FOR /F eol^=^&^ skip^=4^ tokens^=5^ delims^=^" %%i IN (REMOTE_1009.txt) DO (
  ECHO %%i
)
```

[Tthis is the excel equivalent of what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AALg5.png)

[this is the equivalent excel upload , i want to keep that chekbox unchecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6pyV.png)
can anyone help me please
thanks 
aswin

Comment: [nearly answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36372765/2152082). Just use `TAB` instead of `,`

Comment: Hi Stephan i can only use double quotes as delimiter ,

Comment: can you give us a few example lines of `REMOTE_1009.txt` and the expected output?

Comment: What about replacing the double-quotes by tabs, for instance (or anything else not occurring in the data), then using Stephan's suggestion?