# Output buffer not cleared in for loop

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a program that reads a list of hosts and IPs from a CSV file that runs different codes depending on the value of a column. However when outputting the results to a file, the parameters does not seem to refresh.

CSV file (test.csv)

```
Name,FieldA,FieldB,PrimaryIP,SecondaryIP,Type,
ObjA,ABC,DEF,10.1.1.2,Primary,
ObjB,GHI,JKL,10.1.1.3,10.1.2.2,Secondary
```

Batch Script (loop.bat)
ran in CMD using loop.bat test.csv

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims=," %%A IN (%1) DO (    

    if %%F == "Primary" do
    (
        echo Name is %%A
        echo Primary IP is %%D
    )>Primary.txt

    if %%F == "Secondary" do
    (
        echo name is %%A
        echo Primary IP is %%D and Secondary IP is %%E
    )>Secondary.txt


    )
```

output of Primary.txt
Primary.txt is supposed to be ObjA with the IP of 10.1.1.2

```
name is ObjB
Primary IP is 10.1.1.3
```

Output of Secondary.txt
Secondary.txt output is correct though

```
name is ObjB
Primary IP is 10.1.1.3 and Secondary IP is 10.1.2.2
```

Comment: Well, `if %%F == "Primary" do` and `if %%F == "Secondary" do` are both invalid lines for more than one reason. The `FOR` command will fail if there are any spaces in the passed file parameter, and your example `.csv` content is not properly formed.

Comment: the original script runs without issues i just briefly modified it as the actual code contains information pertaining to the product i'm doing. i've included echos in each of the if conditions to ensure that the code block is being executed. only issue is that the output of the text files does not match the expected output. 

my only hypothesis is that the files are only written at the end the for loop thus the buffer might be stuck at the 2nd entry of the csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues here:

1. Your CSV is malformed your missing a comma in the ObjA line moreover you should omit the last comma on each line:

   ```
   Name,FieldA,FieldB,PrimaryIP,SecondaryIP,Type
   ObjA,ABC,DEF,10.1.1.2,[NULL],Primary
   ObjB,GHI,JKL,10.1.1.3,10.1.2.2,Secondary
   ```
2. Two consecutive commas won't work (see [batch-file-tokens-ignore-empty-delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372429/batch-file-tokens-ignore-empty-delimiters)).
3. The `if` conditions won't work you need to enclose them in quotations marks.
4. The `if` syntax is wrong you have to purge the `do`

   ```
   if "%%F" == "Primary" (
   ```

To sum it up:

```
Name,FieldA,FieldB,PrimaryIP,SecondaryIP,Type
ObjA,ABC,DEF,10.1.1.2,[NULL],Primary
ObjB,GHI,JKL,10.1.1.3,10.1.2.2,Secondary
```

```
@echo off
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims=," %%A IN (%1) DO (

    if "%%F" == "Primary" (
        echo Name is %%A
        echo Primary IP is %%D
    )>Primary.txt

    if "%%F" == "Secondary" (
        echo name is %%A
        echo Primary IP is %%D and Secondary IP is %%E
    )>Secondary.txt
)
```

Comment: The `FOR` command will fail if there are any spaces in the passed file parameter. _It will be trying to parse a string, not a file._

Comment: `FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims=," %%A IN ('TYPE "%~1"') DO (`